# npm install -g doesn't work for anything

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm trying to install gatsbyjs using npm using the following command in terminal: npm install -g gatsby-cli. I got a warning and a bunch of errors:

```
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall access
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR!  { Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR!   stack: 'Error: EACCES: permission denied, access \'/usr/local/lib/node_modules\'',
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/simanshrestha/.npm/_logs/2018-07-07T22_48_08_615Z-debug.log
```

I tried reinstalling Node.js and updating npm using: npm install npm@latest -g but only got a bunch of check permission warnings and the following errors:

```
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/cacache/node_modules/ssri
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall access
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/cacache/node_modules/ssri'
npm ERR!  { Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/cacache/node_modules/ssri'
npm ERR!   stack: 'Error: EACCES: permission denied, access \'/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/cacache/node_modules/ssri\'',
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/cacache/node_modules/ssri' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/simanshrestha/.npm/_logs/2018-07-07T22_49_59_092Z-debug.log
```

I've been trying to fix the permission errors, but am stuck (I'm really new to this stuff).

Edit: I don't want to use sudo as I have seen that it could mess things up from multiple forums.

Comment: The error already suggests possible cause, `Please try running this command again as root/Administrator`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 3 possible solutions to your problem, which is basically lack of root access to install modules to root `node_modules` dir:

1. Run `sudo npm i -g package@latest`. This will fix your problem but will ask for root password every time.
2. Change your default global modules folder as outlined [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions) with `npm config set prefix`
3. Install and use [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) to manage `node` and `npm`, it comes out of the box with properly set up folder structure within your local user. So no extra rights needed or messing with config prefixes.

Answer (score 1):

You should run npm install -g as an administrator.

As the console said.